# How to Deserialise Array into List without using Foreach?

Tags: c#, json

I deserialized array into List using for each. But its taking too much time to deserialize when no of records more than 1000. This is my code :

```
 // Access record from API
 string response = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(new Uri(url)); 

 // Decode...                
 var myArray = JArray.Parse(response);

// Deserialize... 

foreach (JObject jo in myArray)
{                   

   var myObject= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<myObject>(jo.ToString());

       myObjectList.Add (myObject);

}
```

So my question is how to deserialize Array without using for each ??
   OR
 Is there any better way to increase performance?

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried: `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<myObject[]>(response)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you tried

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyObject>>(response);
```